# If $x=cy+bz,\,y=az+cx,\,z=bx+ay$ then show that ...

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am stuck on the following problem that says:

> If $x=cy+bz,\,y=az+cx,\,z=bx+ay$ then show that

$x^2:y^2:z^2=(1-a^2):(1-b^2):(1-c^2)$ where ":" indicates ratio.

My try:

The result I got is: $$z(1-a^2)=x(b+ac), y(1-c^2)
 =(a+bc)z\,,x(1-b^2)=(c+ab)y$$

But I don't know how to progress from here.
Can someone help? 
Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: What does $ x^2:y^2:z^2$ mean?

Comment: Ratio of $x^2$ ,$y^2$ and $z^2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $z=bx+ay$, we get
$$x=cy+bz=cy+b(bx+ay)=cy+b^2x+aby\tag1$$ and
$$y=az+cx=a(bx+ay)+cx=abx+a^2y+cx\tag2$$
Multiplying the both sides of $(1)$ by $x$ gives
$$x^2=cxy+b^2x^2+abxy\tag3$$
Multiplying the both sides of $(2)$ by $y$ gives
$$y^2=abxy+a^2y^2+cxy\tag4$$
Now $(3)-(4)$ gives
$$x^2-y^2=b^2x^2-a^2y^2,$$
i.e.
$$(1-b^2)x^2=(1-a^2)y^2$$
I think that you can continue from here.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification...Got it.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Solving $x-cy-bz=0,cx-y+az=0$ for $x,y$

$x=\dfrac{z(ca+b)}{1-c^2},y=\dfrac{z(bc+a)}{1-c^2}$

Similarly, solve for $bx+ay-z=0,cx-y+az=0$ for $x,y$